# XtraReport not showing any data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, devexpress

I have followed the instructions from this documentation [link](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#XtraReports/CustomDocument9974).
The xtrareport shows the box toolbar but it doesnot shows any data. What am I doing wrong?

**In my HomeController.cs**

```
 public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Welcome to DevExpress Extensions for ASP.NET MVC!";
            ViewData["Report"] = new DXApplication.Reports.XtraReport1();

            return View();
        }

       public ActionResult DocumentViewerPartial() 
       {
        ViewData["Report"] = new DXApplication.Reports.XtraReport1();
        return PartialView("DocumentViewerPartial");
        }



        public ActionResult ExportDocumentViewer()
        {
            return DevExpress.Web.Mvc.DocumentViewerExtension.ExportTo(new DXApplication.Reports.XtraReport1());
        }
```

**DocumentViewerPartial.cs**

```
**@Html.DevExpress().DocumentViewer(settings =>
{
    settings.Name = "DocumentViewer";
    settings.Report = (DXApplication.Reports.XtraReport1)ViewData["Reports"];

    settings.CallbackRouteValues = new { Controller = "Home", Action = "DocumentViewerPartial" };
    settings.ExportRouteValues = new { Controller = "Home", Action = "ExportDocumentViewer" };
}).GetHtml()**
```

And Index.cshtml

```
{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";

}
@ViewBag.Message

@Html.Action("DocumentViewerPartial")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try by changing in the DocumentViewerPartial.cs
`ViewData["Reports"]` with `ViewData["Report"]`

Answer (score 0):

In XtraReport1 how do you write? it would be great if you provide your code XtraReport1 or provide us with a simple demonstrating with case.
I saw in your Controller, if you write that, it will get data 3rd:
ViewData["Report"] = new DXApplication.Reports.XtraReport1();

1. The first in Index ()
2. The second in DocumentViewerPartial()
3. The third in ExportDocumentViewer()

Ready you only need get data 1st, you can write:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Welcome to DevExpress Extensions for ASP.NET MVC!";
        return View();
    }

   public ActionResult DocumentViewerPartial() 
   {
    Session["Report"] = new DXApplication.Reports.XtraReport1();
    return PartialView("DocumentViewerPartial");
    }

    public ActionResult ExportDocumentViewer()
    {
        return DevExpress.Web.Mvc.DocumentViewerExtension.ExportTo(Session["Report"] as XtraReport1());
    }
```

And in DocumentViewerPartial.cs you edit:

```
@Html.DevExpress().DocumentViewer(settings =>{
settings.Name = "DocumentViewer";
settings.Report = (DXApplication.Reports.XtraReport1)Session["Reports"];

settings.CallbackRouteValues = new { Controller = "Home", Action = "DocumentViewerPartial" };
settings.ExportRouteValues = new { Controller = "Home", Action = "ExportDocumentViewer" };}).GetHtml()
```

Then final in file Index.cshtml you call:

```
@Html.Partial("ExportDocumentViewer")
@Html.Partial("DocumentViewerPartial")
```

Please perform the corresponding modifications and let me know your results.